# Adding separations and bottom annotation in geom_tile ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I created a heatmap using geom_tile() as follows:

```
df_temp <- df_master
df_temp$X <- c(1:length(df_master$CHR))
df_temp[ ,c('CHR')] <- list(NULL)
df_temp <- melt(df_temp, id.vars="X")

n1 <- length(unique(df_temp$variable))
n2 <- length(unique(df_temp$X))

ggplot(df_temp, aes(x = X, y = variable, fill = value)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())  +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(
            colors=c("grey","orange","dark red"), na.value="grey",
            values=rescale(c(0,5,40)),
            limits=c(0,40)) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(0, n2) + 0.5, y = rep(2:n1, each = 2) - 0.5),
            aes(x = x, y = y, group = y), size=1, colour = 'white', inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

This produced the following [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn1O8.png).

However, the x-axis has a subcategory that groups each observation from 1-20 and is ordered appropriately. I want this to be reflected in the ggplot somehow, with a bottom annotation and maybe some separations inside the heatmap? Excuse my mouse painting skills but something like this:

[image]

So the bottom annotation should be like a single-row colour map that indicates which group the above observations fall under. The black lines would signify exact locations at which these groups are separate.

Is this possible? I've tried going through the internet, but have yet to find a clear answer. Thank you!

EDIT:
Forgot to add what df_temp looks like!

```
> df_temp
      X                variable      value    CHR
1     1                       A  0.3432559 M.m.01
2     2                       A  0.3675018 M.m.02
3     3                       A  0.8010609 M.m.06
4     4                       A  1.3608854 M.m.10
5     5                       A  0.3369016 M.m.13
6     6                       B  1.3765413 M.m.02
7     7                       B  1.5141245 M.m.03
8     8                       B  0.8467624 M.m.05
9     9                       B  0.7612501 M.m.07
10   10                       B  0.8377142 M.m.10
11   11                       B  0.4613787 M.m.13
12   12                       B  1.4047240 M.m.16
13   13                       B  0.9338802 M.m.19
14   14                       B  1.1825244 M.m.20
15   15                       C  0.3156074 M.m.01
16   16                       C  2.3541151 M.m.02
17   17                       C  2.3725061 M.m.05
18   18                       C  1.5970541 M.m.10
19   19                       D  0.3901532 M.m.01
20   20                       D  0.3156074 M.m.02
21   21                       D  2.9405363 M.m.03
22   22                       E  1.5055971 M.m.07
23   23                       E  1.8618063 M.m.08
24   24                       F  0.7314612 M.m.02
25   25                       F  0.7705067 M.m.03
```

Where CHR ranges from M.m.01 to M.m.20 and variable ranges from 6 different categories. This is the result after melt().

Comment: You could do this with facets along the x axis.

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278985/is-it-somehow-possible-to-create-a-bar-chart-in-ggplot2-using-a-multi-grouping-s/72279429#72279429>

Comment: @TarJae Hello! I appreciate the link! It seems that the implementation in that question is for bar graphs, and not for heat maps? Is it possible I could get some guidance on how that could be transferred over to this situation? 
\\ 
`ggplot(df_temp, aes(x = X, y = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = CHR), position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()`
\\ 
Adding the following code seems to be what they do, but it keeps telling me that "continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

Comment: I think it is possible but we need some data to check otherwise for me at least it is not possible to give advice! Just a tip; make a column with the segments and use geom_tile() there. I am sure with a `dput()` @Allan Cameron will give good help. He is the profi here!

Comment: @TarJae The question has been editted with some sample data

Comment: @TarJae I'm still learning! For this answer I had to learn a bit about teunbrand's brilliant ggh4x package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with themed facets using the `ggh4x` package.

The sample data provided doesn't really reproduce your plot, so I have created my own with the same structure for illustration purposes.

```r
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(df_temp, aes(x = X, y = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0:6 + 0.5, color = "white") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
            colors=c("grey","orange","dark red"), na.value="grey",
            values=scales::rescale(c(0,5,40)),
            limits=c(0,40)) +
  facet_grid2(.~CHR, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x", switch = "x",
              strip = strip_themed(
                background_x = elem_list_rect(
                  fill = rainbow(length(unique(df_temp$CHR)))))) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title.x     = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x     = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x      = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.x  = unit(0, "mm"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black", size = 1),
        panel.grid       = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

df_temp <- data.frame(X = rep(1:25, 6),
                      variable = rep(LETTERS[1:6], each = 25),
                      value = runif(25 * 6, 0, 2),
                      CHR = rep(paste("CHR", 
                                      rep(1:5, times = c(6, 4, 3, 7, 5))), 6))
```